# Query empty associations on Sequelize (preferrably v1.7)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models `Pippo` and `Pluto` associated through a `oneToMany` relationship:

```
Pluto.belongsTo(Pippo);
```

What would be the `sequelize` way to retrieve all `Pippo`s that are not associated to any `Pluto`?

BTW: the target DB is `MySQL` and I'd much appreciate a solution compatible with version `1.7` of `Sequelize`

--- EDIT

Basically, if I had to use an SQL query, it would be

```
SELECT * FROM Pippos WHERE pi.id NOT IN (SELECT PippoId FROM Plutos);
```

I guess the question is, is there a way to achieve the same result using `Sequelize` magic?

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify all results which don't have a PlutoId (assuming that PlutoId is the primary key for you Pluto table).

1.7:

```
Pippo
    .findAll({where: {PlutoId: null}})
    .complete(function(err, result) {
         console.log(result); //Pippos without a Pluto
    });
```

2.x +:

```
Pippo
    .findAll({where: {PlutoId: null}})
    .then(function(result) {
         console.log(result); //Pippos without a Pluto
    });
```

Comment: Mmm, this does not seem correct. According to [Sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/), _belongsTo - add a foreign key to source_ which is the reason why I get a *ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR* when I run it. I'd assume that the answer would somehow involve an _include_ constraint but _Pippo.findAll({include: [{model: Pluto, where: {id: null}}]})_ returns _[]_

Comment: I think that is because if you do `{where: {id: null}}` as there isn't a result, there isn't a result with an id of null.

I wonder if this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057302/sequelize-with-join-group-by-having-order-by

With this in mind, you could count return the amount of Plutos for each Pippo and filter out the ones with more than 0 with `having`. (This wouldn't be optimal though)