# Sequelize where has NOT

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an `Article` Sequelize model where articles relate to each other. Some articles are translated copies of other articles. The relation is setup like so:

```
var Article = sequelize.define('Article', {
    type                : DataTypes.ENUM('source', 'translated'),
    sourceArticleId     : DataTypes.INTEGER
});

db.Article.hasMany(db.Article, {
    foreignKey: 'sourceArticleId',
    as        : 'TranslatedArticles'
});
```

So, an article with `type = 'source'` can have many `translatedArticles` where `type = 'translated'`.

Now, I want to query all `source` articles that do not have a translation.

Based on [an issue at the Sequelize project github](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4099#issuecomment-120834551), this would be accomplished like so:

```
Article.findOne({
    where: Sequelize.literal('translatedArticles.sourceArticleId IS NULL'),
    include: [
        {
            model: Article,
            as   : 'TranslatedArticles'
        }
    ]
});
```

Yet when I run this I get:

`SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'translatedArticles.sourceArticleId' in 'where clause'`

I've also tried variations in naming, including `TranslatedArticles.sourceArticleId`, `articles.sourceArticleId`, and `Articles.sourceArticleId`.

Am I missing something?

Note that I temporarily work around this problem by using a literal NOT EXISTS query, like so:

```
Article.findOne({
    where: Sequelize.literal('NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM Articles WHERE Article.id = Articles.sourceArticleId LIMIT 1)')
});
```

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: @yanana version 3.3.1

Comment: Can you turn on the SQL log and see what the sequelize query builder is trying to query for?

Comment: @StevenLu the log is https://gist.github.com/tommedema/5f5ad310a3f31b1dccaa

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what database technology you are using on the backend but I am guessing it is case-sensitive. I believe it isn't finding the field because you need to capitalize the t in translatedArticles. This should work:

```
Article.findOne({
    where: Sequelize.literal('TranslatedArticles.sourceArticleId IS NULL'),
    include: [
        {
            model: Article,
            as   : 'TranslatedArticles'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

mabe i have find the solution, use `subQuery: false`, this option don't have in documentation.

```
Article.findOne({
    subQuery: false,
    where: Sequelize.literal('translatedArticles.sourceArticleId IS NULL'),
    include: [
        {
            model: Article,
            as   : 'TranslatedArticles'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going off the top of my head here, but I think this is how it is the achieved:

```
Article.findOne({
    include: [
        {
            model: Article,
            as   : 'TranslatedArticles',
            attributes: [[models.sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'sourceArticleId'), 'translationCount']]
            having: {
                translationCount: 0
            },
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: This is not returning any articles, because nothing matches the inner where statement.

Comment: Might that revision be closer to the answer?

Comment: this returns `SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'TranslatedArticles.translationCount' in 'where clause'` with generated SQL https://gist.github.com/tommedema/66e8ae5b715b31c337a9

Comment: Amateur mistake! as it is a count i should be using `HAVING` instead `WHERE`

Comment: while it runs, it returns Articles no matter if there are other articles with a `sourceArticleId` equal to the returned article. So, this is not the desired behavior. I need to return source articles that have no translated article, and a translated article is an article where the sourceArticleId equals the source article. The generated SQL is https://gist.github.com/tommedema/fa400097df063ddf5d75

Comment: Hmz. it doesn't seem to be doing the `HAVING translationCount = 0` in the query. Which is from what I understood would be needed to get the desired result. If you look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057302/sequelize-with-join-group-by-having-order-by the last answer archives a similar result in the guy is trying to find all posts with a certain amount of comments

Comment: I'm looking for something else though, more like "posts with no commenst at all" -- which you cannot do with a counter that looks for 0 because that would mean that there are no results at all since the included relation does not exist.

Comment: surely, unless it was a left join which can be accomplished with the `required:false` option within the included model.